# Publish/Subscribe with camel-netty4

Tags: apache-camel, netty, tcp

I have to create a publish/subscribe client.
So this client needs to send a registration call at startup and afterwards, only listens to published updates. The publisher is a 3rd party software, which only can communicate over TCP/IP, so using JMS is no option.

My first idea was to create two routes, one for sending the request and one to receive the results.

```
    // configure clientMode
String rtServerUri = "netty4:tcp://localhost:30600?clientMode=true&decoders=#length-decoder,#string-decoder&encoders=#length-encoder,#string-encoder";

from("quartz://gs/provider?trigger.repeatInterval=15000&trigger.repeatCount=-1")
  .process(exchange -> System.out.println("Trigger registration!"))
  .setBody(constant(registrationBody))
  .to(ExchangePattern.OutOnly, rtServerUri)
;


from(rtServerUri)
  .process(exchange -> System.out.println("Incoming message!"))
  .to("file:test/output?fileName=updates.xml&fileExist=Append")
;
```

Unfortunately this does not work, because two separate connections are established:

[image: Socket connections]

Does anyone have an idea, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are right that you need two routes. But you don't need to create both at the same time. What you can do is disable the second route so that it doesn't start automatically. Then once, the first route has actually sent the message, it will trigger a call to the second route to start. You will have two connections which I don't think is the problem. You just need the listener to get started after you have sent the registration call.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I tried your solution and disabled the listener route at startup.
After the registration call was sent, I started the route by a corresponding Routing policy, and stopped the registration call.
Unfortunately the result is still the same and no further publish events trigger the listener route.

Comment: I put an example project on github: https://github.com/joergjansen/reproduction/tree/master/PublishSubscribe

Comment: Shouldn't .to(ExchangePattern.OutOnly, rtServerUri) be changed to InOnly? I will take a look at the code tonight and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks,
I forgot to mention, that I have to use camel 2.16.4

Comment: By the way, now that I think of it, you shouldn't need two routes. You should somehow tell the netty url that you are connecting as a client and expect a response back. Can you try setting clientMode=true in the url and in your .to set exchangePattern to InOut. Also don't add the second route and test to see what you get as output.

Comment: Have you looked here http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Bi-directional-comms-on-TCP-connection-td5765782.html ?

Comment: Yeah, I saw the previous link, but it did not help and also the exchangePattern make any difference.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, which seems to work for me.

The solution was to create a custom component which extends the NettyComponent. 
The corresponing endpoint will have an reference to the used listener channel (Consumer).

```
@Override 
protected void doStart() throws Exception 
{ 
  super.doStart(); 

  Field nettyServerBootstrapFactory = GsPblConsumer.class.getSuperclass().getDeclaredField("nettyServerBootstrapFactory"); 
  nettyServerBootstrapFactory.setAccessible(true); 
  Object nsbf = nettyServerBootstrapFactory.get(this); 
  Field channel = nsbf.getClass().getDeclaredField("channel"); 
  channel.setAccessible(true); 
  channelToShare = (Channel) channel.get(nsbf); 
  getEndpoint().setSharedChannel(channelToShare); 
}
```

This channel will be used for the Producer to send the messages.

```
@Override 
public boolean process(Exchange exchange, AsyncCallback callback) 
{ 
  ... 
  // get a channel from the pool 
  Channel existing; 
  try { 
    if (getConfiguration().isShareChannel() && getEndpoint().hasChannelToShare()) 
      existing = getEndpoint().getSharedChannel(); 
    else 
      existing = pool.borrowObject(); 
    if (existing != null) { 
      LOG.trace("Got channel from pool {}", existing); 
    } 
  } catch (Exception e) { 
    exchange.setException(e); 
    callback.done(true); 
    return true; 
  } 

  ... 
}
```

If anybody know a better solution, just let me know.

[image: netstat]

After the first route send the request, as outOnly it will be stopped, after the result message is processed by the listener.

```
public class DisableRegisterRoutePolicy extends RoutePolicySupport
{
  @Override
  public void onExchangeDone(Route route, Exchange exchange)
  {
    CamelContext camelContext = exchange.getContext();
    Iterator<InflightRepository.InflightExchange> iterator = camelContext.getInflightRepository().browse().iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      InflightRepository.InflightExchange inflight = iterator.next();

      String id = inflight.getExchange().getExchangeId();
      camelContext.getInflightRepository().remove(inflight.getExchange());
    }

    Route regRoute = camelContext.getRoute("gs-registration-route");
    try
    {
      camelContext.stopRoute(regRoute.getId());
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

More details could be found here: http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/publish-subscribe-with-camel-netty4-tp5801431.html

Thanks, 
Jörg